# Determining number of files in Ubuntu One

Tags: files

Is there a way of telling in Ubuntu One how many files I have in each folder without having to do a manual count?

Comment: When you log in to the Website it shows how many files you have and how much storage they use.

Answer (score 1):

When you log in to the Website it shows how many files you have and how much storage they use. – Uri Herrera Jul 22 '11 at 12:47